# Identical ImageButtons consume huge amount of memory

Tags: android, memory-leaks, imagebutton

I've just recently started developing Android apps and facing memory issues. Using the Allocation Tracking feature of Android studio I figured out that four ImageButtons which are displayed on multiple Activities are most likely to cause the problem. The allocation tracking result shows almost all memory is being used by two methods regarding images. See:
[Allocation Tracking result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1ony.png)

The drawables for the buttons are small icons with roughly *20 KB* in size and are located in **drawable-nodpi**. This way Android shouldn't have to do anything about scaling them.
Starting the App and just switching between two activities showing those four ImageButtons for a few times, is enough to run OOM. The activities are started normally with a specific **launchMode** by:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, MyActivity.class));
```

Isn't Android supposed to destory activities currently not in use in order to free memory. Instead I get an increasing memory usage graph like this: [Memory Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDo6A.png)

What are good practices to lower the resources needed for recurring ImageButtons? Is there a way for me to remove them explicitly in for example **onDestory()**?

Answer (score 0):

`no-dpi` means it's not meant for density scaling, not "it doesn't scale at all, ever".

If you have 1 pixel `no-dpi` drawable and you display it at 640x480 (scaling as fit or cover), android will decode the resource at 640 * 480 * 4 bytes = ~1.2 MB. Yours seem to be around 55 and 35 MB, so I am assuming you scale them to be the entire screen, or big at least.

Starting a new activity over and over will just build a stack. Since you're still active in the same task stack (you're just adding on top of it), Android won't just destroy the activity; this is different from going to a different task stack (read: launch a different app, which puts this app in the background).

Resource recycling is handled by the `ImageButton` and `Button` classes, so you don't need to explicitly handle that. If you want to manually do this:

- don't inflate the drawable in your layout (so remove `drawableXXX=...` or `src=...`)
- load the image using `Bitmap.decodeResource`
- here you can set small sizes and the `BitmapFactory.Options`
- manually call `Bitmap#recycle` when you're done

If you load these in `onCreate`, recycle in `onDestroy`; if you load these in `onStart`, recycle in `onStop`; if you load these in `onResume`, recycle in `onPause`.

Comment: The icon images used with the ImageButtons are around 600x600, and are displayed next to each other at the bottom of the screen, see: http://i.imgur.com/VE0hEzX.png
As the recycling is handled by the ImageButton itself, is this just an issue coming from the drawables being in the wrong directory?

Comment: I'm actually assuming something else is happening. The memory usage for a single button is ridiculous. Honestly, since these are not vector images (or large background images), I would put them in mdpi, and let android scale them for density. It will look way better.